# Unmarked Cruiser in single player campaign

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I'm playing GTA V on Xbox One and have updated to the heist update already.

After researching and playing a bit, I discovered that the only way for Michael and/or Trevor to get a Vapid Stanier Unmarked Cruiser is to steal one, as Franklin, when doing a weed delivery mission, either for Barry or for Smoke on the Water, then blow up the van (you'll lose profits for a week, but hell, for an unmarked cruiser it's worth it, for me, at least), drive Franklin near Michael/Trevor, switch to Michael/Trevor, take the unmarked cruiser, and place it in a garage.

Is this the only way to get an unmarked cruiser for Michael/Trevor? I know in the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions that it spawns at the train station in Strawberry, but I'm not on Xbox 360; I'm on Xbox One.

Has anyone encountered an unmarked cruiser in *single player campaign*?

Answer (score 1):

According to IGN, the Unmarked Cruiser can be found in Strawberry at night at the U-shaped Los Santos Transit bus terminal, under the Olympic Freeway. A variety of Police Vehicles spawn here, but the Police Cruiser in question most commonly spawns between 9PM and Midnight.

Sourche: [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Unmarked_Cruiser)